# Recurring billing with Rails and ActiveMerchant: Best practices, pitfalls, gotchas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, payment, recurring-billing

We are prepping for the release of a large web application that has been in development for the past year. We are about to start the process of integrating ActiveMerchant to handle recurring subscription fees for the service.

I am looking for any advice regarding best practices considering our requirements (listed below) and any additional heads-up for common pitfalls or specific issues I should be giving special consideration. The payment gateway we will be using is [PaymentExpress](http://www.paymentExpress.com.au) as it's one of the few supported gateways that has recurring billing and doesn't have any special conditions for companies operating outside of the USA. The business behind this application is based out of the UK.

Users of the application create an account with a sub-domain where they can access and customise the application and their data. Below are some of the requirements/features that might have an effect on how billing works:

- All users get a 30 day trial
- There are different plans, including a free one
- Higher priced plans have larger limits on the amount of data (e.g. users, projects,  etc) they can have in their account
- Billing period will be monthly, beginning after trial
- There will be discounts/coupon codes to get a percentage off the normal price for a year on plans, etc.
- Plan pricing will change as features are added

Specific hurdles I can foresee will be things including the following:

- How to handle downgrading when they violate the plan limits for lower level plans.
- Behaviour when credit cards expire or payments don't go through (a read-only mode enforced, perhaps)
- When plan pricing changes, we want to honour previous prices for existing users for a time period (such as 6 months), then start charging higher rates. If the plan price decreases, it will take effect immediately.

Other advice that would be helpful would be anything regarding flow of the application. How should billing forms be presented to the user? When should credit card information be required? How should invoices be sent, stored, and accessible?

I should disclose that we plan to base a lot of the code base off [SaaSy](http://github.com/maccman/saasy/tree/master). SaaSy is designed to be used as a separate Rails app that handles all the signup and account management side of things. However, this doesn't work for us since we never planned for this from the beginning and it would be a tedious process to adapt our application to work like that. Consequently, we'll be pulling code and ideas from SaaSy and merging them into our app, a considerably less tedious task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RailsKits](http://railskits.com/) has a [Software as a Service kit](http://railskits.com/saas/) that should do what you need.  It has built-in support for free trials, upgrading, downgrading, plan limits, etc., and it supports PaymentExpress (and some others).

I've researched it a bit for a project I'm doing, but I haven't purchased it yet so I can't vouch for it.  However, I have seen a few blog posts praising this kit.

While the RailsKit is relatively inexpensive when compared what it would cost you to implement all of its features yourself, there are a couple open source versions out there that aim to accomplish the same thing.  The one I remember off the top of my head is called [Freemium](http://code.google.com/p/freemium/).

EDIT: I forgot to mention that Ryan Bates said in his [most recent Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant) that his next episode or two will deal with recurring billing, so keep an eye out for that.  He usually does one episode per week, and the five he's done since December 22 all cover handling payments of different types.

Comment: Yes I have been following the screencasts from Ryan and I have also seen RailsKit. The problem is that RailsKit is designed as a starting point for an app, not an addition to an existing one. My question is less of a technical one than architecture/design best practice one. Thanks though!

Comment: BTW, many people use the SaaS Rails Kit with their already-existing app... they just copy over the models, controllers, etc.  So, you don't have to start from scratch to use it.

Answer (score 8):

One thing I wanted to add: keep in mind you don't need to use the recurring billing feature that is built into the gateway.  In general these systems are legacy and very difficult to deal with, we get spoiled in the rails world.

You get a lot more flexibility just using them for one purpose (to bill a credit card, and perhaps also store credit cards for PCI compliance).  Then roll your own recurring billing in your rails app with a cron job, a date field for when they are paid through, and amount each person is paying (in case they used a coupon) etc.

One small example: sometimes people will cancel a monthly subscription in the middle of the month.  They want to make sure they don't forget to cancel before the next payment.  Most gateway recurring billing that I've seen will instantly terminate the account (or send you a message indicating this).  In reality, the user has paid through the end of the month and should be given 2 more weeks of access.  You can do this if you have rolled your own recurring billing in rails, but not if you are using the gateway recurring billing.  Just a small example.

Answer (score 4):

Peepcode has a PDF for sale(70 pages) that details various aspects of payment processing and industry practices for this. It may be worth checking out:

http://peepcode.com/products/activemerchant-pdf

Comment: I've had a look at the book, I was looking for a bit more than this

Comment: The book provides a great overview of the process and include many code snippets. The author also covers had to create unit tests. There is also a sample app included: moneyhats. Great content and value for a very affordable price.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also in the middle of setting up a subscription based website and these are our current requirements. They may help you regarding best practice:

- Users will be able to choose one of
  the subscription plans.
- Users will be required to enter their
  credit card details to sign up to
  their chosen plan.
- All major credit and debit cards must
  be accepted including Maestro and
  American Express.
- Each plan will have a 30-day free
  trial so users' credit cards should
  only be charged after the 30-day
  period expires. However, the validity
  of credits cards should be checked at
  the time of sign up.
- Users will be emailed a few days
  before their credit card is charged
  to notify them that they will be
  charged soon unless they cancel their
  account. If they cancel their account
  within their 30 day free trial, their
  credit card should not be charged.
- After any free trial period, users
  will be charged in advance for their
  use of the system - ie they will
  pre-pay.
- Users will be charged automatically
  every month for their chosen plan.
  Each month, users will be sent an
  email a few days in advance to notify
  them that they will be charged. Once
  payment has been made, users will be
  emailed an invoice showing that their
  payment has been received.
- Users will be able to upgrade or
  downgrade their accounts at any time.
  When users upgrade/downgrade, their
  next subscription charge will be at
  the new rate. Users will only be able
  to downgrade their accounts to a plan
  that can handle their data. For
  example, if they currently have 10
  active projects they can't downgrade
  to the Basic plan because the Basic
  plan only allows 5 projects. They
  will have to delete or archive 5
  projects before you they can
  downgrade to Basic.
- Users will be able to log in to their
  account and change or update their
  credit card details.
- Users will be able to cancel their
  account at any time. There will be no
  further subscription charges after a
  user has canceled their account.
  However, users will not be refunded
  for part of the month they have
  already paid for.
- All parts of the payment system must
  be 100% PCI DSS compliant; including
  any 3rd party systems.
- The payment system must support
  automated notification and retry of
  failed subscription renewals.
- The payment system must support
  discount vouchers with expiry dates.
- Credit card details must not be
  processed by or stored on our servers
- they should always be processed/stored by our 3rd party
  payment processing partner. We do not
  want responsibility for securing
  these details and complying with
  legal rules and regulations.
- Users will be able to log into their
  accounts and see a full billing
  history including dates and amounts
  paid. We will also need to be
  able to log in to a system to see
  customer payment plans and payment
  history. This will be essential for
  customer service.

We've also been looking at http://chargify.com/ which looks like it could save a lot of coding time.