# What the pros and cons of PayPal's recurring Subscribe button versus their other plans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm trying to get recurring payments to work on my Rails site.

I have two options:

1. Recurring Payments via the PayPal Subscribe button API (http://ianpurton.com/adding-paypal-subscription-to-your-rails-appl)
2. Recurring Payments via ActiveMerchant and PayPal Express (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471936/recurring-billing-with-rails-and-activemerchant-best-practices-pitfalls-gotcha)

My monthly payments are going to be cheap (less than $5/mo).  I only need one paid plan (a pro plan) and don't plan on adding additional plans.  I also expect volume to be very modest ... and is meant to help cover some of my server expenses.

For me the biggest factors:
- Ease of adding this to my site.
- Least amount of surchages and monthly minimums

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to transfer control of the subscriptions, it's hard to do since the subscriptions are tied to a specific paypal account / email account